# Which version of Apache Camel SpringBoot Starter to use for Spring Boot 2.5.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, build.gradle

From Maven Central: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-spring-boot-starter

This is what the dependency seems to be:

org.apache.camel.springboot » camel-spring-boot-starter:3.11.0 depends on org.springframework.boot » spring-boot-starter    2.5.1

org.apache.camel.springboot » camel-spring-boot-starter » 3.10.0 depends on org.springframework.boot » spring-boot-starter  2.4.5

Which one should we use in a project which runs Spring Boot 2.5.0

Would the lower one be compatible or the higher one.

I guess what I am asking is... if Camel Spring Boot Starter wants (at-least?) spring-boot-starter   2.4.5, then would it be okay with Spring Boot 2.5.0 being there is the project already, or would it import Spring Boot 2.4.5?

I would like to understand how the dependency works.

**Update:**

I tried camel-spring-boot-starter:3.11.0 with a project which runs Spring Boot 2.5.0. And spring-boot-starter   2.5.1 is not seen in the expanded dependencies. Doesn't camel-spring-boot-starter:3.11.0 need/bring-in spring-boot-starter  2.5.1?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the list of versions via `camel version list` command (camel-jbang)

```
~/workspace/camel main *13 ❯ camel version list --runtime=spring-boot --minimum-version=3.0
 CAMEL VERSION   SPRING-BOOT     JDK   KIND     RELEASED     SUPPORTED UNTIL
     3.1.0      2.2.4.RELEASE    8,11         February 2020
     3.2.0      2.2.6.RELEASE    8,11            April 2020
     3.3.0      2.2.7.RELEASE    8,11              May 2020
     3.4.0      2.3.0.RELEASE    8,11  LTS        June 2020        June 2021
     3.4.1      2.3.1.RELEASE    8,11  LTS        July 2020        June 2021
     3.4.2      2.3.1.RELEASE    8,11  LTS        July 2020        June 2021
     3.4.3      2.3.2.RELEASE    8,11  LTS      August 2020        June 2021
     3.4.4      2.3.4.RELEASE    8,11  LTS   September 2020        June 2021
     3.4.5      2.3.4.RELEASE    8,11  LTS    December 2020        June 2021
     3.4.6      2.3.10.RELEASE   8,11  LTS        June 2021        June 2021
     3.5.0      2.3.3.RELEASE    8,11        September 2020
     3.6.0      2.3.4.RELEASE    8,11        September 2020
     3.7.0          2.4.0        8,11  LTS    December 2020     January 2022
     3.7.1          2.4.2        8,11  LTS     January 2021     January 2022
     3.7.2          2.4.2        8,11  LTS    February 2021     January 2022
     3.7.3          2.4.3        8,11  LTS       March 2021     January 2022
     3.7.4          2.4.5        8,11  LTS         May 2021     January 2022
     3.7.5          2.4.8        8,11  LTS        July 2021     January 2022
     3.7.6          2.4.11       8,11  LTS     October 2021     January 2022
     3.7.7          2.4.11       8,11  LTS    December 2021     January 2022
     3.8.0          2.4.2        8,11         February 2021
     3.9.0          2.4.4        8,11            March 2021
    3.10.0          2.4.5        8,11              May 2021
    3.11.0          2.5.1        8,11  LTS        June 2021        July 2022
    3.11.1          2.5.3        8,11  LTS      August 2021        July 2022
    3.11.2          2.5.4        8,11  LTS   September 2021        July 2022
    3.11.3          2.5.5        8,11  LTS     October 2021        July 2022
    3.11.4          2.5.6        8,11  LTS    November 2021        July 2022
    3.11.5          2.5.8        8,11  LTS    December 2021        July 2022
    3.11.6          2.5.10       8,11  LTS       March 2022        July 2022
    3.11.7          2.5.13       8,11  LTS         May 2022        July 2022
    3.12.0          2.5.5        8,11          October 2021
    3.13.0          2.5.6        8,11         November 2021
    3.14.0          2.6.1        8,11  LTS    December 2021    December 2023
    3.14.1          2.6.3        8,11  LTS     January 2022    December 2023
    3.14.2          2.6.4        8,11  LTS       March 2022    December 2023
    3.14.3          2.6.7        8,11  LTS         May 2022    December 2023
    3.14.4          2.6.8        8,11  LTS        June 2022    December 2023
    3.14.5          2.6.10       8,11  LTS      August 2022    December 2023
    3.14.6          2.6.13       8,11  LTS    November 2022    December 2023
    3.14.7          2.6.13       8,11  LTS    December 2022    December 2023
    3.15.0          2.6.3          11         February 2022
    3.16.0          2.6.4          11            March 2022
    3.17.0          2.6.7       11,17              May 2022
    3.18.0          2.7.1       11,17  LTS        July 2022        July 2023
    3.18.1          2.7.2       11,17  LTS      August 2022        July 2023
    3.18.2          2.7.3       11,17  LTS   September 2022        July 2023
    3.18.3          2.7.5       11,17  LTS     October 2022        July 2023
    3.18.4          2.7.6       11,17  LTS    December 2022        July 2023
    3.18.5          2.7.8       11,17  LTS     January 2023        July 2023
    3.18.6          2.7.8       11,17  LTS       April 2023        July 2023
    3.19.0          2.7.3       11,17          October 2022
    3.20.0          2.7.6       11,17  LTS    December 2022    December 2023
    3.20.1          2.7.7       11,17  LTS     January 2023    December 2023
    3.20.2          2.7.8       11,17  LTS    February 2023    December 2023
    3.20.3          2.7.10      11,17  LTS       March 2023    December 2023
   4.0.0-M1         3.0.2          17   RC    February 2023
   4.0.0-M2         3.0.4          17   RC       March 2023
```