# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver on Spring Boot 2.7.1, Camel 3.18.0 and JDK 11

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, pom.xml

I keep running into this error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver` even though I don't have it in my code. After a bit of research I found out that Camel actually uses this dependency and it was an error starting from Spring Boot 2.x ([camel issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12340)). I also saw that this issue was resolved since [Camel 2.21.0](https://camel.apache.org/releases/release-2.21.0/#:%7E:text=to%20freegeoip.net-,CAMEL%2D12340,-camel%20uses%20org)

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

<!-- Camel -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-xml</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

According to this thread [Which version of Apache Camel SpringBoot Starter to use for Spring Boot 2.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76024678/which-version-of-apache-camel-springboot-starter-to-use-for-spring-boot-2-5-0) Spring Boot 2.7.1 is supported with Camel 3.18.0. I tried testing around with different Spring Boot and Camel version but this issue still shows up. Any idea what I could have done wrong/ am missing?